# Laravel user_id forign key not working

Tags: foreign-keys, migration, acl, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I have multiple registration types I have tried to add a foreign key following the aravel 5.2 documentation and it keeps giving me errors any help would be greatly appreciated.  I need to connect the registration of each type of user into the different registration types.  Below I will post one of the three registration types that I have.  If there is a way to only add the user information to the user table after there email has been verified that would be great.  So in other words each registration (3x) I need them to fill out registration and only the user table info goes to the user table the rest would go to the other table but I want to two to be connected.

This is the migration file I am trying to get to work following the laravel 5.2 documents.

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
   public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('artists');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('artists')
            //->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
     }

   /**
      * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
      */
   public function down()
   {

    Schema::drop('users');
   //$table->dropForeign('artists_user_id_foreign');
   }
   }
```

I also tried doing the same thing on the artists table and it did not work either keep getting a foreign constraint issue.

Ill need to do that process for each type of user account.

The controller is set up like this for artist

```
  <?php 

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Artist;

     use App\User;
    use App\Artist;
     use App\Mailers\AppArtMailer;
      use Illuminate\Http\Request;
      use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


    class RegistrationController extends Controller
    {
    //protected $redirectTo = 'art';
    /** Create a new registration instance.
     */
     public function __construct()
     {
        //$this->middleware('artist');
     }
     /** show the Register page/
      * 
      * @return \Response
      */
    public function register()
    {
        return view('art.register');
    }
    /**
     * Perform the registration.
     *
     * @param  Request   $request
     * @param  AppMailer $mailer
     * @return \Redirect
     */

    public function postRegister(Request $request, AppArtMailer $mailer)
    {
        //Validate
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:artists',
                'password' => 'required'
            ]);
        //create artist
        $artist = Artist::create($request->all());
        $user = User::create($request->all());

        //email them

        $mailer->sendEmailConfirmationTo($artist);
        //$mailer->sendEmailConfirmationTo($user);
        //flash
        flash('Please confirm your email address.');

        // redirect

        return redirect()->back();

    }
    /**
     * Confirm a user's email address.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function confirmEmail($token)
    {
        Artist::whereToken($token)->firstOrFail()->confirmEmail();

        flash('You are now confirmed. Please login');

        return redirect('artist');



      }


       }
```

I also followed  the laracast ACL Roles and Permissions but am not sure how to integrate that into each of the user registrations so that each type automatically has the set roles.

Here are the different models I have each is a bit different since I am learning and playing.

﻿
Artist Model This will actually change since they can only be an artist if they are a viewer.

```
namespace App; 


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword; 
use App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticatedArtist; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract; 

class Artist extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract 
{ 
protected $table = 'artists'; 


use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword; 

/** 
     * The database table used by the model. 
     * 
     * @var string 
     */ 


    /** 
     * The attributes that are mass assignable. 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 

   protected $fillable = [ 
       'name', 'email', 'password', 
    ]; 

   /** 
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form. 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected $hidden = [ 
        'password', 'remember_token', 
  ]; 
 /** 
   * Boot the model. 
     * 
     * @return void 
      */ 



            public static function boot() 
       { 
    parent::boot(); 

    static::creating(function($artist) { 
        $artist->token = str_random(30); 
    }); 
    } 
   /** 
          * Set the password attribute. 
          * 
          * @param string $password 
         */ 

public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
{ 
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
} 
 /** 
        * Confirm the user. 
       * 
         * @return void 
        */ 

public function confirmEmail() 
{ 
    $this->verified = true; 
    $this->token = null; 

    $this->save(); 
} 
    }
```

This is my users model

```
<?php 

namespace App; 

use DB; 
use Illuminate\Http\Response; 
use App\Http\Controllers; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; 
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Traits\Messagable; 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; 

class User extends Authenticatable 
{ 
use HasRoles, Messagable; 

     //* The attributes that are mass assignable. 
     //* 
    // * @var array 
    // */ 
    protected $fillable = [ 
        'name', 'email', 'password', 
    ]; 
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
    { 
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
    } 
    /** 
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays. 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected $hidden = [ 
        'password', 'remember_token', 
    ]; 

// $user->roles 

}
```

Sponsors Model

```
    <?php 

    namespace App; 


    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable; 
    use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword; 
    //use App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticatedSponsor; 
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract; 
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract; 

    class Sponsor extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,             CanResetPasswordContract 
    { 
    protected $table = 'sponsors'; 


    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword; 

    /** 
       * The database table used by the model. 
      * 
      * @var string 
      */ 


      /** 
        * The attributes that are mass assignable. 
        * 
       * @var array 
       */ 

        protected $fillable = [ 
           'name', 'email', 'password', 
       ]; 

       /** 
         * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form. 
         * 
         * @var array 
        */ 
        protected $hidden = [ 
            'password', 'remember_token', 
        ]; 
     /** 
         * Boot the model. 
         * 
         * @return void 
         */ 



    public static function boot() 
    { 
    parent::boot(); 

    static::creating(function($sponsor) { 
        $sponsor->token = str_random(30); 
        }); 
    } 
        /** 
       * Set the password attribute. 
         * 
     * @param string $password 
     */ 

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
    { 
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
    } 
     /** 
     * Confirm the user. 
     * 
     * @return void 
     */ 

public function confirmEmail() 
{ 
    $this->verified = true; 
    $this->token = null; 

    $this->save(); 
} 
}
```

Viewer Model

```
<?php 

namespace App; 

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable; 
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Traits\Messagable; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword; 
use App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticatedViewer; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract; 

class Viewer extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract 
{ 
    protected $redirectTo = 'viewer'; 
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, Messagable; 

    /** 
    * The database table used by the model. 
    * 
    * @var string 
   */ 
   protected $table = 'viewers'; 
//protected $table = 'experience'; 
   /** 
     * The attributes that are mass assignable. 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 

    protected $fillable = [ 
        'name', 'email', 'password', 
    ]; 

  /** 
   * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form. 
     * 
    * @var array 
    */ 
    protected $hidden = [ 
        'password', 'remember_token', 
    ]; 

    public function experience() 
    { 
    return $this->hasOne('App\Experience'); 
    } 

    public function awardExperience($points) 
    { 
    return $this->experience->award($points); 
    } 
     /** 
     * Boot the model. 
     * 
     * @return void 
     */ 
    public static function boot() 
    { 
    parent::boot(); 

    static::creating(func
```

Comment: Can your users only be 1 or the 3 types or potentially all of them? Also can you add your `User` and `Artist` models to your post?

Comment: They will either be just a sponsor or just a viewer. If they are a viewer they can create an artist account.